# Im trying to pluck more than one value in PHP Filament v3

Tags: php, laravel, web, laravel-filament

I am trying to pluck more than one value. I want firstname and lastname. How do i get both values to show up.

```
    SelectFilter::make('participant_id')
                    ->attribute('participant_id')
                    ->label(__('messages.participant_model_firstname'))
                    ->options([
                        array_unique(
                            Participant::all()
                                ->pluck('firstname', 'id')
                                ->toArray()
                        )
                    ]),
```

I found nothing really interesting on the internet to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, don't call `all()` unless you want to return everything from the database, instead call `pluck()` on the eloquent query builder so that only the name and id columns are loaded, saving memory and cpu processing.

Create a new column `fullname` by joining `firstname` and `lastname`:

```php
Participant::query()
  ->select([
    DB::raw("CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) as fullname"),
    'id',
  ])
  ->pluck('fullname', 'id')
  ->toArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this for a while, finally got it working thanks to post above.
Here is my slightly different implementation. I am creating label, not a field etc.

```php
Placeholder::make('Custome Placeholder:')
->content(function (Get $get) {
    $list = User::query()
        ->select([\DB::raw("CONCAT(name, ' ', lastname) as fullname"), 'email'])
        ->where('active', '==', $get('active')) // Replace 'column_name', 'operator', and 'value' with your actual conditions
        ->pluck('fullname', 'email')
        ->toArray();
    $html = "<ul>";
    foreach($list as $key => $value){
        $html .= "<li style='padding-bottom: 5px; margin-bottom: 7px;' class='relative flex gap-x-1 rounded-lg px-2 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 outline-none transition duration-75 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:bg-gray-100 dark:text-gray-200 dark:hover:bg-white/5 dark:focus:bg-white/5 font-medium bg-gray-100 text-primary-600 dark:bg-white/5 dark:text-primary-400'>";
        $html .= '<svg class="w-5 inline-block" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1.5" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M8.25 4.5l7.5 7.5-7.5 7.5"></path></svg>';
        $html .= "<a class='dark:text-primary-400' href='/admin/user/". $key . "/edit'>" . $list[$key] . "</a></li>";
    }
    $html .= "</ul>";
    echo !empty($list) ? $html : '<div class="text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">No active associated users found</div>';
})
```

My actual model returns more different details.